# aggregate tick data to open high low close non time related

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to consolidate tick data stored in a pandas dataframe to the open high low close format but not time related, but aggregated for every 100 ticks. After that I would like to display them in a candlestick chart using matlibplot.

I solved this already for a time related aggregation using a pandas dataset with two values: TIMESTAMP and PRICE. The TIMESTAMP already has the pandas date format so I work with that:

```
df["TIMESTAMP"]= pd.to_datetime(df["TIMESTAMP"])
df = df.set_index(['TIMESTAMP'])
data_ohlc =  df['PRICE'].resample('15Min').ohlc()
```

Is there any function, that resamples datasets in the ohlc format not using a time frame, but a count of ticks?

After that it comes to visualization, so for plotting I have to change date format to mdates. The candlestick_ohlc function requires a mdate format:

```
data_ohlc["TIMESTAMP"] = data_ohlc["TIMESTAMP"].apply(mdates.date2num)
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
candlestick_ohlc(ax1,data_ohlc.values,width=0.005, colorup='g', colordown='r',alpha=0.75)
```

So is there any function to display a candle stick chart without mdates because by aggregating tick data there would be no time relation?

Answer (score 1):

As there seems to be no build in function for this problem I wrote one myself. The given dataframe needs to have the actual values in the column "PRICE":

```
def get_pd_ohlc(mydf, interval):

    ## use a copy, so that the new column doesn't effect the original dataset
    mydf = mydf.copy()

    ## Add a new column to name tick interval
    interval = [(1+int(x/interval)) for x in range(mydf["PRICE"].count())]
    mydf["interval"] = interval

    ##Step 1: Group 
    grouped = mydf.groupby('interval')

    ##Step 2: Calculate different aggregations 
    myopen = grouped['PRICE'].first()
    myhigh = grouped['PRICE'].max()
    mylow = grouped['PRICE'].min()
    myclose = grouped['PRICE'].last()

    ##Step 3: Generate Dataframe:
    pd_ohlc = pd.DataFrame({'OPEN':myopen,'HIGH':myhigh,'LOW':mylow,'CLOSE':myclose})

    return(pd_ohlc)

pd_100 = get_pd_ohlc(df,100)
print (pd_100.head())
```

I also found a solution to display ist. Module mpl_finance has a function candlestick2_ohlc, that does not need any datetime information. Here is the code:

```
#Making plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_finance import candlestick2_ohlc

fig = plt.figure()
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16,8)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=12, colspan=1)

#Making candlestick plot
candlestick2_ohlc(ax1, pd_ohlc['OPEN'], pd_ohlc['HIGH'],
                  pd_ohlc['LOW'], pd_ohlc['CLOSE'], width=0.5,
                  colorup='#008000', colordown='#FF0000', alpha=1)
```